# How can I model this relationship (avoiding loops)?

Tags: mysql

In MySQL... This might not be the very best example of the relationship I'm after, but it's essentially what I'm trying to do in my DB (this is very simplified from my complete data model).

Suppose we have a table called author, and a table called book.

- 'DB.author': author_id, author_name
- 'DB.book': book_id, book_name, author_id
  (this is an identifying relationship)

Now let's say we have a table called reader with columns for favorite author and favorite book. Every reader has a favorite author, but they don't all have a favorite book. If they do have a favorite book, it must have been written by their favorite author.

- 'DB.reader': reader_id, reader_name, favorite_author_id, favorite_book_id

I can't just remove the favorite_author_id column, because favorite_book_id could be null. Is it possible to model this relationship and avoid loops?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps have a `reader_favorite` table with `reader_id`, `favorite_type`, and `favorite value` where `favorite_type` could be a book or author. You could then LEFT JOIN from `reader` to `reader_favorite` and then LEFT JOIN to both `book` and `author` from the `reader_favorite` table.

You're then only saddled with making sure that if the reader has an entry for both `book` and `author` favorite types in the `reader_favorite` table, that the two values agree, but that was already an issue so: no harm, no foul.

Answer (score 0):

You could try having separate table: favourites: object_id, object_type, (or something like that), then you would have single column in reader table for favourite id. This would also be somewhat more extensible, though it still ain't very nice.

Another option (in general) could be constraints (and keeping your described structure), though for I think that is problematic with MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. Turns out I was able to make this work using foreign key constraints in MySQL/InnoDB. I didn't think I could have a composite foreign key that sometimes includes null values, but it works as expected.

```
CREATE TABLE `author` (
  `author_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `author_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`author_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `book` (
  `book_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `book_name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `author_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`book_id`,`author_id`),
  KEY `fk_book_author` (`author_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_book_author` FOREIGN KEY (`author_id`) REFERENCES `author` (`author_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `reader` (
  `reader_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `reader_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `favorite_author_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `favorite_book_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`reader_id`),
  KEY `fk_reader_favorite_book` (`favorite_book_id`,`favorite_author_id`),
  KEY `fk_reader_favorite_author` (`favorite_author_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_reader_favorite_author` FOREIGN KEY (`favorite_author_id`) REFERENCES `author` (`author_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_reader_favorite_book` FOREIGN KEY (`favorite_book_id`, `favorite_author_id`) REFERENCES `book` (`book_id`, `author_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```